# Async HttpPost requests - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm trying to make an async HttpPost requests with Ajax & MVC.
I know that SessionId is the problem: multiple requests from the same client with the same SessionId will add the second request to the queue.
after I google it I saw some answers for this it fails to me.

1. I tried to clear session data.
2. I tried to add an mvc attribute to change session mode to readOnly:

   ```
   [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
   public class TestController : SurfaceController
   {
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Test1()
       {
           Thread.Sleep(5000);
           return Json("1");
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Test2()
       {
           Thread.Sleep(5000);
           return Json("2");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: the bottom line of my question - the result got response in 5 secounds, 10 secounds for the secound.

Comment: The bottom line of your question is not a question? What is your question?

Comment: How do you test it?

Comment: I want to make an async multiple httppost requests, how can i make it async?